# How can I run a connectedAndroidTest against the release build?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to test an android application's release build using the instrumentation tests.

It looks like the default connectedAndroidTest gradle command is only available for debug builds.
Is there a way to configure it for release builds ?

Answer (score 4):

You can test instrumentation test for release build by setting below line in your
**app/build.grad**le file

```
android {
    testBuildType "release"
}
```

or through Android studio terminal/command prompt by below command

```
gradlew connectedAndroidTest  -PtestBuildType=release
```